# The proper algebraic steps to solving $4^z = 64$ for all complex solutions?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

I recently looked at the equation $$4^z = 64$$ and wanted to solve for all complex solutions. The original problem I came across was a social media "test your knowledge" problem that became equivalent to solving $4^x = 64$ in the reals, but I decided to extend it to go a step further. I'm confident that I have arrived at the correct solution set but I do not know whether the process of getting there is valid. And if it isn't I'm very curious on what the correct process is.

$$4^z = 64$$

Essentially what I have done is take the Complex Log of both sides, which I will denote as $Ln(z)$

$$Ln(4^z) = Ln(64)$$
$$zLn(4) = Ln(64)$$
$$z \ln(4) = \ln(64) + 2\pi i k$$ for all $k \in \Bbb{Z}$

From here I arrive at
$$z = 3 +\frac{2\pi i k}{\ln(4)}$$ for all $k \in \Bbb{Z}$

---

However looking back on it I have to wonder if one is allowed to just take the Complex Log of both sides like that, and only have the $2 \pi i k$ term appear on one side of the equation, or if it would need to show up on both sides. Most of what I know about Complex Logs is self taught and online reference, but I couldn't find much at all on finding complex solutions to an exponential equation with a base that isn't $e$.

After a while of searching I decided to try and bring $e$ into the equation and try a second method:

$$4^z = 64$$
$$e^{\ln(4^z)} = 64$$
$$e^{z \ln(4)} = 64$$
$$e^z = 64^{1/\ln(4)}$$
$$z = Ln(64) / \ln(4)$$
$$z = \frac{\ln(64) + 2\pi i k}{\ln(4)}$$ for all $k \in \Bbb{Z}$
And then I arrive at the same solution set. Could this be the proper algebraic steps that need followed? Once again I have my doubts on simplifying $e^z$ to $z$ being a valid step.

Any explanations on the rules behind solving this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$ we have
$$e^{z_1}=e^{z_2}\iff z_1=z_2+2\pi i k\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
So your equation is, by definition, equivalent to
$$e^{z\ln{(4)}}=e^{\ln{(64)}}\iff z\ln{(4)}=\ln{(64)}+2\pi i k\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
where any branch of the complex logarithm is used.

Note that the solution implicitly depends on the branch of the logarithm used to define $4^z$ (which is in general multivalued).

Comment: Using this fact makes the problem much more straightforward; no logs are getting taken on both sides of the equation. Thank you